# When the main() function is called back the program is terminated. Is there a way I can fix this?

Tags: c

I have to write a c program to manage the reservations. When I call back the main function the program gets terminated without continuing. How can I fix this error? ( I haven't written the whole program)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
 int i, j, day, x;
 char session[10];
 int array[2][5] = {{0,0,1,0,1},{1,1,0,0,0}};
 char response,ans,choice;

 printf("**************** WELCOME TO NAT RESERVATION SYSTEM ****************");

 printf("\n\nCHOOSE WHAT TO DO");

 printf("\n\n\t\tA.\t\tBOOK THE THEATER");
 printf("\n\t\tB.\t\tCHECK RESERRVATIONS");
 printf("\n\t\tC.\t\tREMOVE RESERVATIONS");
 printf("\n\t\tD.\t\tCALCULATE INCOME");
 printf("\n\t\tE.\t\tEXIT");

 printf("\n\nYOUR RESPONSE\t\t:  ");
 scanf("%c",&response);


 switch (response){
   case 'A': printf("\n\nBOOK THE THEATER"); break;
   case 'B': printf("\n\nCHECK RESERRVATIONS"); break;
   case 'C': printf("\n\nREMOVE RESERVATIONS"); break;
   case 'D': printf("\n\nCALCULATE INCOME"); break;
   case 'E': printf("\n\nEXIT"); break;
 }

 if (response == 'A'){

  printf("\n\nCHOOSE A DAY   :   ");
  scanf("%d",&day);
  j = day -1;

  printf("YOUR SESSION     :   ");
  scanf("%c",session);
  fgets(session,10,stdin);

  if(strcmp(session,"MORNING")){
    i = 0;
  }else if(strcmp(session,"AFTERNOON")){
    i = 1;
  }else{
    printf("PLEASE ENTER MORNING OR AFTERNOON");
  }

  if(array[i][j] == 0){
    printf("\n\nTHE SESSION IS AVAILABLE.\nDO YOU WANT TO CONFIRM THE BOOKING?(Y/N)   :   ");
    scanf("%c",&ans);
```

I want to direct the program to print the main menu. So I called back the main() function here.

```
    if(ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y'){
      array[i][j] = 1;
      printf("\nYOUR BOOKING WAS SUCCESSFUL!\n\n");
      main();
    }
  }else if(array[i][j] == 1){
    printf("\n\nTHE SESSION IS NOT AVAILABLE.");
    printf("DO YOU WANT TO TRY ANOTHER SESSION?(Y/N):  ");
    scanf("%c",&ans);

    if(ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y'){
      main();
    }else if(ans == 'N' || ans == 'n'){
      printf("THANK YOU! HAVE A NICE DAY!");
      exit(0);
    }
  }  
 }
}
```

I tried to use a while loop. I don't know what to put inside the brackets. Please help me. I'm new to C programming as I learned most of them online.

```
while(1){
 printf("**************** WELCOME TO NAT RESERVATION SYSTEM ****************");


printf("\n\nCHOOSE WHAT TO DO");

printf("\n\n\t\tA.\t\tBOOK THE THEATER");
printf("\n\t\tB.\t\tCHECK RESERRVATIONS");
printf("\n\t\tC.\t\tREMOVE RESERVATIONS");
printf("\n\t\tD.\t\tCALCULATE INCOME");
printf("\n\t\tE.\t\tEXIT");

printf("\n\nYOUR RESPONSE\t\t:  ");
scanf("%c",&response);


switch (response){
  case 'A': printf("\n\nBOOK THE THEATER"); break;
  case 'B': printf("\n\nCHECK RESERRVATIONS"); break;
  case 'C': printf("\n\nREMOVE RESERVATIONS"); break;
  case 'D': printf("\n\nCALCULATE INCOME"); break;
  case 'E': printf("\n\nEXIT"); break;
}

if (response == 'A'){

  printf("\n\nCHOOSE A DAY   :   ");
  scanf("%d",&day);
  j = day -1;

  printf("YOUR SESSION     :   ");
  scanf("%c",session);
  fgets(session,10,stdin);

  if(strcmp(session,"MORNING")){
    i = 0;
  }else if(strcmp(session,"AFTERNOON")){
    i = 1;
  }else{
    printf("PLEASE ENTER MORNING OR AFTERNOON");
  }

  if(array[i][j] == 0){
    printf("\n\nTHE SESSION IS AVAILABLE.\nDO YOU WANT TO CONFIRM THE BOOKING?(Y/N)   :   ");
    scanf("%c",&ans);

    if(ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y'){
      array[i][j] = 1;
      printf("\nYOUR BOOKING WAS SUCCESSFUL!\n\n");
      continue;
      main();
    }
  }
  if(array[i][j] == 1){
    printf("\n\nTHE SESSION IS NOT AVAILABLE.");
    printf("DO YOU WANT TO TRY ANOTHER SESSION?(Y/N):  ");
    scanf("%c",&ans);

    if(ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y'){
      continue;
      main();
    }else if(ans == 'N' || ans == 'n'){
      printf("THANK YOU! HAVE A NICE DAY!");
      exit(0);
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Don't call main recursively, learn to use a loop instead.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I tried to use while loop but the menu gets printed twice. How can I fix that?

Comment: Use `fgets()` for user input. Don't mix `getchar()` and `scanf()`.

Comment: Then show that code.

Comment: @SouravGhosh  okay. I edited the question above.

Comment: @pmg when I remove scanf() it doesn't let me input anything and print the next lines.

Comment: @Nathali: use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` instead. Ie: replace `scanf("%x%y", a, b, ...);` with `fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin); sscanf(line, "%x%y", a, b, ...);`

Comment: @pmg okay. Thank you. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original program without `while` and `continue` seems to work fine if you use *scanf* with the format string `" %c"`, that is insert a blank space before the percentage sign. This makes the program skip leading white space. Without the leading space in the format string the newline characters in the input will not be skipped over.

NOTE: It is also better to print a newline at the end of a string. If I choose B, for instance, the program output does not end with a newline so on a non-Windows machine the command prompt (in my case a dollar sign) is displayed on the same line as the output:

```
CHECK RESERRVATIONS$
```